# About which is the highlighted information added?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The horses, needless to say, were not mentioned again. Tom and Miss
>   Baker, with several feet of twilight between them, strolled back into
>   the library, as if **to a vigil beside a perfectly tangible body**,
>   while, trying to look pleasantly interested and a little deaf, I
>   followed Daisy around a chain of connecting verandas to the porch in
>   front. In its deep gloom we sat down side by side on a wicker
>   settee.
>  (F. Scott Fitzgerald, The Great Gatsby)

About which is the highlighted information added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The highlighted phrase is referring to Tom and Miss Baker, and it is describing how they strolled back into the library. It seemed like they were participating in a [vigil](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/vigil). I take the writer to mean that they were moving silently, as during a vigil people avoid making unnecessary noises, for respect of the person.

Comment: I'm Sorry, I missed a word 'to.' Now I get the meaning well with the 'to.'